# Convert XY reference to pixel reference

Tags: vb.net

I have a panel with a `backgroundimage` simulating a XY graph as you can see in the image below.

I am creating `pictureboxes` dynamically based on the user inputs:

- number of images
- (X,Y) coordinates

[image: PanelPng]

The problem is the coordinates are defined in a native machine software, with a range of `X and Y from -100 to +100` . My panel is 200px x 200px.

I was trying something like:

```
If X < 0 and then 
   X0 = X-100
ElseIf X > 0 then 
   X0 = X+100
Else 
   X0 = X
End If

(...)
PictureBox(n).location = new point ( X0,Y0 )
```

But i think it is not good to do something like this. Any idea to do this in a better way ?

----EDIT----

Best approach so far :

```
Select Case X And Y
            Case CInt(X < 0 And Y > 0)
                X0 = X + 100
                Y0 = Y - 100
            Case CInt(X < 0 And Y < 0)
                X0 = X + 100
                Y0 = Y + 200
            Case CInt(X > 0 And Y > 0)
                X0 = X + 100
                Y0 = Y + 100
            Case CInt(X > 0 And Y < 0)
                X0 = X + 100
                Y0 = Y + 200
            'Missing when X=0 and so on
End Select
```

----EDIT----

Now look at the example.

All the answers you are giving don't fit the question.

```
| X  | Y  | | X0 | Y0  |
|-100|100 | | 0  | 0   |
| 20 | 40 | |120 | 60  |
| -60|-20 | | 40 | 120 |
|  60|-80 | | 160| 180 |
```

[image: cartesian vs panel location]

Comment: Would [Modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) help?

Comment: @UweKeim Looks like ye ! I'ma search a similar function to test it !

Comment: so your panel is 500px x 500px or 200px x 200px? and you want to convert from (-100 to 100) to (0 to 500)? if yes you can do simply: `(X+100)*(500/200)` where 200 is distance of -100 to 100

Comment: @S.Serp Forget the 500px ! It is a 200px panel, with values from 0 to 200px in each direction. But my input goes from -100 to 100 !

Comment: So it must be `X+100`, (as this will be 0 for -100 and 200 for 100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `X0 = X + 100` and `Y0 = 100 - Y` should work! for example:

- if X=-100 then X0 is 0,
- When X=0 then X0 is 100
- when X=+100 the X0 is 200,

So when `X` is between -100 to 100, `X0` will be between 0 and 200 as you want!

**Edited as:**  `Y0 = 100 - Y` 
Checked with your sample data and its ok

- if Y=-100 then Y0 is 200,
- When Y=0 then Y0 is 100,
- when Y=+100 the Y0 is 0.

Comment: As i said, `What if the input is X=-100 and Y=50 ? It doesn't work properly.. Y=50 in a graph is different than Y=150 in a panel..`

Comment: I updated the answer as  `Y0 = 100 - Y`  please review and accept it if its ok

Comment: I was seeing this wrong. Now it makes sense! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert Cartesian coordinates to screen to coordinates.

```
    Dim xmin As Integer = -100
    Dim xmax As Integer = 100
    Dim xrng As Integer = xmax - xmin

    Dim ymin As Integer = -100
    Dim ymax As Integer = 100
    Dim yrng As Integer = ymax - ymin

    Dim center As New Point(xrng \ 2, yrng \ 2) 'center on screen
```

Once we have center then other Cartesian coordinates can be converted to screen coordinates.

```
    Dim newcpt As New Point(-50, 50) 'new cartesian pt
    Dim drawpt As New Point(center.X + newcpt.X, center.Y + newcpt.Y) 'new cartesian pt translated to screen location
```

Comment: I need an approach because of the quadrant it fits. It doesn't work everytime like that. See the edit !

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is to flip the Y and then translate the origin. From panel
 to cartesian.

```
x0 = x - 100
y0 = -(y - 100)
```

Do the opposite for the other way around.

```
x0 = x + 100
y0 = -y + 100
```

[image]

Comment: @i.Dio have you tried the second formula in my answer? It will give the same output from the input you have.

Comment: yes. it works fine using only "part of the image" ( the last one ). But it's a backgroundimage in the panel, i can't show only part of it

Comment: @i.Dio I don't understand, the formula work for all 4 coordinate.

Comment: it's true. I accepted the first answer ! And thank you !